# How to calculate chance of occurrence based off a sample

Tags: probability, odds

I found this interesting study that shows basically how much more likely you are to get divorced based on certain factors of your marriage. It goes down to the cost of your wedding ring.

See [here](http://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=171094066115020088117113096011122096025047071016027028067090069098013031005031075102030099002020054112125067118066087112096115038073039053068117011095071114078109024058060020003099091023030006019065028004081114068098074114022085075026005093072003118&EXT=pdf)

I'd like to write a program that calculates the chances of your divorce based on your factors. All the stats are based off a reference though, for instance it'll say you're 10% more likely to get divorced if you're Black, but 21% less likely to get divorced if you're Hispanic compared to Whites.

How do I got about doing this? Do I get a base percentage from another source and then keep multiplying these likelihood percentages?

Here's a table from the study.

[image]

Comment: Actually the price of the wedding ring seems to be one of the weaker factors and in any case it will be correlated with several of the other factors.  Remember that correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: You will not be able to take just a probability and multiply it because it appears this is a proportional hazards model. You will need a baseline function describing the instantaneous hazard rate of divorce for a marriage with baseline characteristics. You will then multiply that rate function by your various factors and then calculate the cumulative risk over a certain time period, e.g., 10 years, 20 years. I'll take a closer look in an hour or so :-) PS there is also a get around if you only have a cumulative risk baseline

Comment: @tristan Would something like this work as a baseline? http://www.divorcestatistics.org/

Comment: @Henry So does that mean I can't accomplish what I want with this study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. First a very brief introduction to survival analysis and Cox regression...

Survival analysis is the study of random variables corresponding to times to events, e.g., how long does a laptop component last before breaking down, how long do people survive after being diagnosed with cancer?

We will very often want to look at the survivor function $S(t)$, which is the graph of the proportion surviving (not yet experienced the event) across time ($t$). The survivor function is related to the cumulative distribution function (or cumulative risk function), $F(t)$ through the relationship $S(t)=1-F(t)$.

We will also often want to know about the hazard rate $\lambda(t)$, which is the *instantaneous* rate of the event occurring. For continuous survivor functions:

$$
  \lambda(t) = \frac{\frac{d}{dt} \left[ F(t) \right]}{S(t)} = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = \frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}
$$

The situation is slightly different for discrete time survival analysis, but it's not a big issue - [see here for details on this and survival analysis in general](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7.pdf).

Cox regression is a way to estimate how the hazard rate $\lambda(t)$ is dependent on covariates or predictors.

It basically assumes that the hazard function for each unit (e.g., laptop component, patient, marriage) can be decomposed into the hazard ratios and a baseline hazard function:

$$
  \lambda_i(t|x_i) = \lambda_0(t) \exp\{x_i^\prime\beta\}
$$

In this equation, $x_i$ is a vector of characteristics of the unit and $\beta$ is the vector of coefficients, and $\lambda_0(t)$ is a baseline hazard function which is completely independent of the covariates.

The hazard ratio for the $j$th component of $x_i$ ($x_{ij}$) is $\exp\{\beta_j\}$. These are often reported instead of the $\beta_j$ because they are easier to interpret.

Additionally, there is the very neat property that if there is hazard ratio applied throughout, the survivor function is modified in a very simple way:

$$
  \lambda^\prime(t) = c \lambda(t) \Leftrightarrow S^\prime(t) = (S(t))^c
$$

In other words, if you multiply the hazard rate by a constant $c$, it has the effect of raising the survivor function to the power $c$.

So where does this all leave you?

You have a set of hazard ratios for a number of covariates (I suggest using Table 3 as it is based on recent marriages). You also have a population average cumulative risk of divorce from http://divorcestatistics.org (although I might look elsewhere to get more explicit sources and timeframes).

Unfortunately, the population average cumulative risk does not correspond to the reference categories against which the hazard ratios are calculated, instead it is effectively the weighted average cumulative risk weighted across the joint distribution of the covariates.

Now, this is not a million miles from the cumulative risk if you apply the average covariate values, but this is only an approximation. It's the best we can do.

Table 1 gives you the average covariate values (unfortunately for the whole population, not the recently married, so perhaps Table 2 would be better for you in the end for hazard ratios).

So, for example, taking the covariate, "Employment":

1. According to the American Community Survey 2012, 0.59 were employed full time, 0.16 employed part time and 0.25 other.
2. The reference category is employed full time, so its hazard ratio is 1 by definition. The hazard ratios for employed part time and other are 1.020 and 0.867 respectively (for all - you would probably want to do separately for men and women).
3. The "average hazard ratio" is then $0.59\times 1 + 0.16\times 1.020 + 0.25\times 0.867 = 0.970$
4. If your user is employed full time you then apply a hazard ratio of $\frac{1}{0.970} = 1.031$, whereas if they are employed other you apply a hazard ratio of $\frac{0.867}{0.970} = 0.894$
5. So if your cumulative risk (at some time) was 40%, then your survivor function was 0.6 (60%). So raise 0.6 to the power of the hazard ratio (1.031 for employed full time, 0.894 for employed other). The survivor function goes to 0.59 for employed full time (i.e., cumulative risk goes from 40% to 41%) and to 0.63 for employed other (i.e., cumulative riskgoes to 37%).
6. You apply these hazard ratios for all the variables the user supplies and in the end you get a value out which is hopefully not too far wrong!

Hope that makes some sense!

**[EDIT]** Oh, and one thing you could also try! Contact the authors to see if they will share the baseline hazard function $\lambda_0(t)$ or baseline survivor function $S_0(t)$

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on the last step, number 6? I can't just consecutively apply the ratios over and over can I? For instance, I'll be at 30% chance to get divorced by the 7th factor down. Then one of the factors will turn out to be a very high hazard, and it'll throw the percentage all the way up to 70% or something. Perhaps a result of it not being weighted?

Comment: You can get issues if the 'baseline' is not very representative, even when you have access to the data to calculate a proper baseline survivor function. I suggest you contact the authors to ask for the baseline (for the reference categories). Also you could try restricting your calculations to a few key variables.

Comment: May I use your explanation above on my website?

Comment: Go for it. No need for attribution, just use what you want as you want.